# webpack Error: custom keyword definition is invalid: data/errors should be boolean

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm using webpack to bundle two js files(test.js and index.js)
This is how test.js looks like

```
console.log("i'm in test.js");
export default 35;
```

This is how index.js looks like

```
const num = require("./test");
console.log("Successfully export the number: " + num);
```

This is how my package.json file looks like

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },

 "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
```

I'm getting this error when I run the command "npm run dev" both of my files are working correctly.

`````
> forkify@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter
> webpack

C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:231
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: custom keyword definition is invalid: data/errors should be boolean
    at Ajv.addKeyword (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\ajv\lib\keyword.js:65:13)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\ajv-errors\index.js:10:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\schema-utils\src\index.js:7:25)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:13:25)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\webpack\lib\WebpackOptionsApply.js:16:32)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Seinfeld\Desktop\js\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Seinfeld\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-10T08_30_11_517Z-debug.log````

Anyone who knows the answer please tell me.
Thanks in advance
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually bug from webpack itself. You can downgrade to another version.

Here is the [Issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8768)

#### If you use yarn

add below to package.json

```
  "resolutions": {
    "ajv": "6.8.1"
  }
```

then run `yarn install`

#### if you use npm

```
npm uninstall ajv
npm install ajv@6.8.1
```

Comment: I don't even use ajv. I'm only using these two packages. a. webpack b. webpack-cli

Comment: see the [package.json](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/package.json) `ajv` is using by webpack.

Comment: Glad to hear that!